# use MyPy on unittest setUp and tearDown methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mypy

I wonder how to apply mypy on unittest code.
Situation:

```
class TestPoint(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.point_origin = Point(0, 0, 0, name="origin")

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.point_origin = None

    def test_point_coordinates(self) -> None:
        self.assertIsInstance(self.point_origin.x, (float, int))
        self.assertIsInstance(self.point_origin.y, (float, int))
        self.assertIsInstance(self.point_origin.z, (float, int))
```

This results in:

```
tests\test_geometry.py:114: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "Point")
```

Now I can fix this inside the code to check if `self.point_origin` equals None, but the entire point was to tear down the fields before each test.

Should I just skip mypy in the test files? Or is there a better way to apply mypy on test code and/or change my test setup?

Comment: If you want to satisfy mypy, you have to type `self.point_origin` as `Optional[Point]`, otherwise the type will be inferred as `Point`. Apart from that - setting `self.point_origin` to `None` is not needed in `tearDown`, as the instance is deleted anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Removing the tearDown in this case is enough. Optional[Point] would mean I have to catch this optional in every test. Which isn't what I wanted either.